# Proof of $xy\ge4$ with $x=z+\frac{1}{p}$ and $y=p+\frac{1}{z}$, where $x,y,z,p \in R$ $x,y,z,p\gt0$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider following set of equations:
$$x=z+\frac{1}{p}$$
$$y=p+\frac{1}{z}$$
Where $$x,y,z,p \in R$$$$x,y,z,p\gt0$$
How to prove:
$$xy\ge4$$

Comment: What have you tried - e.g. multiply the expressions you have for $x$ and $y$ and see what you can do with the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be easier if you prove the following first.

Lemma: Let $r>0$. Then $r + \frac{1}{r} \geq 2$.

> Proof: Assume toward a contradiction that $r=2-\epsilon$ where $0<\epsilon<2$. Then $r+\frac{1}{r}=2-\epsilon$ and $r^2 + (\epsilon-2)r + 1=0$. Using the quadratic formula and solving for $r$ gives $r = \frac{(2-\epsilon) \pm \sqrt{\epsilon (\epsilon - 4)}}{2}$, where the term under the radical is negative. Thus there is no real solution, which contradicts $r$ being real. $\square$

You can now easily prove $xy\geq 4$, by substituting in for $x$ and $y$ and applying the lemma to $zp$.

Comment: This is completely off topic, but how did you put the box around your proof? Furthermore, how do you hide it?

Comment: To put a box around something, all you do is put $>$ at the beginning of a paragraph. To have it hidden, you use $>!$ instead. It's all explained [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: Here is an easier proof of the lemma.  Let f be defined on the positive reals by f(x) = x + 1/x.  Use calculus to show that the minimum value of f is 2.

Comment: @Browning Yes, that will work too. That was how I went about it at first, but I felt like calculus was a bit much to prove such a simple result. And I am not so sure that it is simpler. Showing $f'(1)=0$ and $f''(0)>0$ feels like a lot more work to me. I feel like there might be an even simpler proof which doesn't rely on the quadratic formula and uses purely the properties of $\mathbb R$, but I don't know what that might be. That said, I feel like this proof is fairly simple and is probably the best one I can come up with.